# How to load a file whose link is stored in my database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am storing a file on my laptop and the path of that file in my database. How do I load the contents of the file using sql? Is it possible or am I supposed to use php to get the link from my database table and then use some kind of load file function in php?

Comment: Use `file_get_content` function of php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Cric already mentioned you should use the `file_get_content();` function to load the content of a file like this:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( $mysql->file );
?>
```

best regards.